# Logarithm identity question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Can anyone explain how this identity results in the RHS?

Thank you

[image: A]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know that $$\log_b m^n=n\log_b m.$$

This is true since we have that $$m^n=(b^{\log_b m})^n=b^{n\log_b m}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Got it $log_b(x^{-y}) = -y*log_b(x)$